# Pass Data from input form to ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I Have a List of projects and three type of payments for any project I Want to give all type of payments and send payment id to ajax But I give just id=1 for all request my Code is here:

```
@foreach($project->payments as $payment)
    @if($payment->type==1)
        @if(empty($payment->code))
            <input type="hidden"id="payment_id"value="{{$payment->id}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paymentCode" name="paymentC">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <button id="AddCode"  type=submit class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
        @else
            {{$payment->code}}
        @endif

     @elseif($payment->type==2)
         @if(empty($payment->code))
             <input type="hidden" id="payment_id" value="{{$payment->id}}">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paymentC" id="paymentCode">
             {{csrf_field()}}
             <button id="AddCode" type="submit" class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
         @else
             {{$payment->code}}
         @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('.AddCode').click (function (event) {
    var payment_id = $('#payment_id').val();
    var paymentCode = $('#paymentCode').val();
    console.log(payment_id);
});
```

How I Can fix my problem that When click in button of payment print this id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach($project->payments as $payment)
    @if($payment->type==1)
        @if(empty($payment->code))
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" id="payment_id" value="{{$payment->id}}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="paymentCode" name="paymentC">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <button id="AddCode" class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
            </div>
        @else
            {{$payment->code}}
        @endif

     @elseif($payment->type==2)
         @if(empty($payment->code))
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" id="payment_id" value="{{$payment->id}}">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paymentC" id="paymentCode">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <button id="AddCode" class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
            </div>
         @else
             {{$payment->code}}
         @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('.AddCode').click (function (event) {
    var payment_id = $(this).closest('div').find("#payment_id").val();
    var paymentCode = $(this).closest('div').find("#paymentCode").val();
    console.log(payment_id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not targetting an unique id with `var payment_id = $('#payment_id').val();`

Change this line of html

```
<button id="AddCode" type="submit" class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
```

Into

```
<button value="{{$payment->id}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-info generate-label AddCode">enter</button>
```

JQuery

```
$('.AddCode').on("click", function(event){
    var payment_id = $(this).val(); // payment id
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique for individual HTML entity.

Code Update:

```
{{csrf_field()}}
@foreach($project->payments as $payment)
    @if($payment->type==1)
        @if(empty($payment->code))
            <input type="hidden"id="payment-id-1"value="{{$payment->id}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payment-code-1" name="payment_code">
            <button type=submit class="btn btn-info generate-label add-code" data-payment=1>enter</button>
        @else
            {{$payment->code}}
        @endif

    @elseif($payment->type==2)
        @if(empty($payment->code))
            <input type="hidden" id="payment_id_2" value="{{$payment->id}}">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="payment_code" id="paymentCode">

             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info generate-label add-code" data-payment=1>enter</button>
        @else
            {{$payment->code}}
        @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Javascript Code:

```
$('.add-code').on("click", function(event){
    var payment_type = $(this).data("payment");
    var payment_id = $('#payment-id-'+payment_type).val();
    var paymentCode = $('#payment-code-'+payment_type).val();
});
```

Try this out. Not tested.